# CSS Bottom Not Working When Combined with Top?

Tags: css, margin

I am attempting to create a top and bottom margin for a div and when I specify only the bottom margin it works correctly:

```css
#RightBar{
  display: block;
  position: fixed;
  height: 100%;
  width: 25px;
  bottom: 150px;
  right: 0px;
  background: Aqua;
}
```

```html
<div id="RightBar"></div>
```

However when I add the top margin, the bottom margin all of a sudden doesn't work at all - it's almost as if it no longer reads it:

```css
#RightBar{
  display: block;
  position: fixed;
  height: 100%;
  width: 25px;
  bottom: 150px;
  top: 25px;
  right: 0px;
  background: Aqua;
}
```

```html
<div id="RightBar"></div>
```

Any ideas on what may be causing this?

Comment: `top` and `bottom` are positioning attributes, not a `margin`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's because you also have a `height` declaration of `100%`, which can't fit between your `25px` `top` and your `150px` `bottom`. A conflict results in one of the rules being ignored, usually the oldest one.

Remove the `height` to fix this. You don't need it now that the height can automatically be calculated from the `top` and `bottom`:

```css
#RightBar{
  display: block;
  position: fixed;
  width: 25px;
  top: 25px;
  bottom: 150px;
  right: 0px;
  background: Aqua;
}
```

```html
<div id="RightBar"></div>
```